# How to generate random number as an id / primary key of an object in Django

Tags: django, random, primary-key

How do you generate a unique, random number to set as the primary key of an object in django?

EDIT - The random number doesn't have to be the primary key, but it needs to be unique for each object such that I can reference/get/call the object by that number.

Comment: You just want a random key value, outside of the auto-incrementing id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe just generate a uuid?

```
>>> from uuid import uuid4
>>> uid = uuid4()
>>> uid
UUID('88016297-726a-4a42-a5d3-7c1047e27cac')
>>> uid.int
180782199398610579001229174541650132140L
>>> uid.hex
'88016297726a4a42a5d37c1047e27cac'
>>> uid.bytes
'\x88\x01b\x97rjJB\xa5\xd3|\x10G\xe2|\xac'
```

Long uuid's are meant to avoid collisions and guarantee within a high degree, uniqueness. If you need a shorter id, this will depend on how you intend to use it. If it needs to be unique across all models because you will use it as a root url, `/<slug>/`, then it will increase your need to query the database checking for uniqueness before assigning it.

You might want to look at using a [slugfield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield), and a [snippet like this](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/690/) which sets a unique slug value on model save.

In a nutshell...long UUID == instant value. Shorter slug value == query loop to confirm uniqueness.

Comment: I'm planning on using this id in my url for the object it describes. I'm a big buff on pretty urls though -- is there a way to create a shorter random number that is still unique? The uniqueness with UUIDs seems to come from its long length

Comment: Well does this have to be unique across all your models? Or is this going to be rooted under a namespace per model in your urls? The longer uuid is intended to prevent collisions.

Answer (score 5):

Any randomly generated number uniqueness is constrained by how big the space for generating random numbers is. UUID/GUIDS are 128 bits long, and so have a low chance of collision. However all UUIDs except version 4 ones are not completely random (even with those, one nibble is fixed at `0x4`), and as such, one sub part of a UUID cannot be considered unique (See [Raymond Chen's post on GUIDs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/05/23/10309199.aspx) for more information, also note that although he works for Microsoft, and most of his columns are Microsoft related, this one applies to anything using UUIDs/GUIDs).

So, let's not consider UUIDs for this purpose. What first needs to be decided is how large of a space you need, then an encoding scheme can be decided on that fits your needs. This heavily depends on how many items you want to refer to. Because of the [Birthday Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), the chance of running into a collision between two randomly generated numbers is surprisingly low, with an approximation provided by the [Birthday Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack) page on Wiki, which is:

[image]

H is the number of possible values, and Q(H) is how many items we can generate before experiencing a collision. I'm going to assume that collisions are undesirable, since to check for one, more than likely you will have to hit your database to see if the generated number exists, if it does, create another and check it again. As you get more and more items in your database, this process will take longer and longer. You still will want to check for collisions, of course, but the chance that you should have to check more than once should be very low.

So, let's start with a 32 bit value. From the formula above, you will have about 82,000 items generated before you can expect a collision. If you're expecting only a few thousand, or a few tens of thousand, this could be an acceptable number of bits to work with. For a few other values, here's the amount of items generated for a number of bits:

```
16 bits: 320
24 bits: 5100
32 bits: 82,000
40 bits: 1.3*16^6
48 bits: 2.1*10^7
64 bits: 5.4*10^9
```

I would consider these counts to be a maximum you would expect to have in your table. If it is security related, I would chose a range much much larger than what you need (Externally visible user ID you don't want people to guess others, and a few hundred users max? 48 bits is the minimum I would be comfortable with there)

On a specific note I would generate these numbers with [random.getrandbits()](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.getrandbits) for non-security related items, for those, I would use [ssl.RAND_bytes()](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ssl.html#ssl.RAND_bytes) instead.

Now, for the other part of the problem: encoding these random bits into something printable. The most basic would be hex encoded, which we be `0-9A-F`, and the length will be the number of bits you generated divided by 4 (a 32 bit identifier would be 8 characters, 40 bits 10, etc). This would be case insensitive and easiest to type.

Another option would be base-64 encoding. This will result in an output (1/6)*n (rounded up) characters (where n is the number of bits). So for 32 bits, 6 characters, 40 bits, 7 characters, etc. Base 64 values are case sensitive, and care has to be taken if one is to be put into a URL (+ and / are both part of base 64 encoding, and could be replaced with . and _ for example, for URL encoding). This will make them harder to type, but shorter for larger values (11 characters for base64 vs 16 for hex for 64 bit values, and this savings increases).

While this doesn't directly answer your question (although I imagine you know how to assign a value for storage in your database, and keep in mind, these values should either be stored in their string encoded forms in the database, or as BLOBs, as your database might treat some of these values as signed, and cause bad things), it should give you what you need to know in order to figure out the correct combination for your application.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can do it with a Django model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from random import randint


class Account(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='account',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self):
        if not self.id:
            is_unique = False
            while not is_unique:
                id = randint(1000000000000000000, 1999999999999999999) # 19 digits: 1, random 18 digits
                is_unique = Account.objects.filter(id=id).exists()
            self.id = id
        super(Account, self).save()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me a lot.

PS: You can use Account.objects.filter(id=id).exists() instead of ...count() == 0

Comment: This keeps us in the while loop forever. Add a `not` before Account.objects.filter(id=id).exists()

Comment: Add *args and **kwargs to the `save` and `super` method to avoid errors when passing variables.

Answer (score 0):

**H Rayan**'s answer will loop forever. so here an fix.

```
from django.db import models
from random import randint


class Account(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            # if create new tree
            is_id_exist = True
            while is_id_exist:
                id = randint(100000, 1000000)
                is_id_exist = Account.objects.filter(id=id).exists()
                
            self.id = id

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```